# current session error opening REPL in emacs with CIDER

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I've been following a tutorial and hit an error where there wasn't one in the book. I have reinstalled leinigen, updated java and reinstalled cider on emacs.

But doesn't seem to help and I can't find this error message online. Running M-x "cider-jack-in" to open a REPL gives me the error message:

"Symbol’s function definition is void: sesman-current-sessions"

and I can't figure out what's causing this, any help is gratefully received.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem. It's possible that you're using an old version of the `sesman` package. Updating `cider` for me didn't update the `sesman` dependency.

For example, `sesman-20180903.1826` doesn't define `sesman-current-sessions` while `sesman-20181109.1100` does. Updating `sesman` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: out of curiousity, what book/tutorial is this?

Comment: how did you update sesman? I ran the package-refresh-contents command then package-reinstall sesman, but still get the same error.

***scratch that, I'm an idiot. Had to run cider with project.clj not core.clj

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your `project.clj` file? Maybe it contains old versions of libraries that are either conflicting with the newest CIDER.

A typical minimal `project.clj` from a fresh new project created with `lein new app myapp` will look like this:

```
(defproject myapp "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "EPL-2.0 OR GPL-2.0-or-later WITH Classpath-exception-2.0"
            :url "https://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-2.0/"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]]
  :main ^:skip-aot overflow.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

Comment: Denis, to your question on the other answer, it's "Clojure for the brave and true", and for your answer it's literally the bog standard "lein new app myapp" and i changed one print statement (but it works via "lein run")

Comment: ***edit***
I'm an idiot, had to run cider under project.clj not core.clj